# file system sync

Tags: linux, backup, filesystems

I'm currently using rsync to keep a copy of a filesystem. This rsync constantly runs and keeps the backup up to date (in theory, its not particularly reliable). Is there a better way to keep a remote up to date snapshot of a filesystem (I'm unable to change the FS type to one with this built in - the source is on a NAS unit).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is rsync acting unreliable for you?  In my experience it is very reliable, so I suspect there is more to your situation that you are not telling us.

Comment: You need to provide details of the NAS.

Comment: Unreliable in the aspects of keeping it continuously running. The data copies themselves are fine, but keeping a continuous rsync of the filesystem is proving troublesome.

Comment: NAS is a netapp filer. The source drive is mounted from that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with block device level replication with [DRBD](http://www.drbd.org/), it's de facto standard for this purpose (and it's even included in mainline Linux kernel starting from 2.6.33).

Comment: Thanks. The source data is mounted from a netapp so I'm unable to use DRBD, otherwise taht would have been a good step.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use [glusterfs](http://www.gluster.org/), which is very simple to set up.

Or check out inotify which you can set up to run the rsync only when something changes on the filesystem.

Check out http://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki example 1 for how to do this.

Comment: inotify sounds like it might be just the ticket. Thats the main issue with rsync, getting it to consistently copy the data. I'll check that out. Thanks.